# Method procedure + switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
static double rSetzen(){
    double r;
    System.out.println("Sind sie männlich oder weiblich?");
    String gender = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    switch(gender){
        case "männlich": r = 0.7; break;
        case "weiblich": r = 0.6;break;
        default: System.err.println("Dies war nicht gefragt"); rSetzen();break;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I have a problem with my piece of code (above), why isn't `r` initialized and what could I do better?

Comment: What happens when only the `default` is executed, ie. not the other cases?

Comment: I think it would restart, isnt that called recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r` is not initialized because

- It is declared without the `= <some value>`, and
- There is a code path from `double r` to `return r` (namely, when the `switch` takes the `default:` branch) that does *not* assign `r` any value.

There are several ways of fixing it - one is to declare `r` with an initial value, like this:

```
double r = 0;
```

Another one is to make sure that the `default:` branch assigns `r` some value:

```
default:
    System.err.println("Dies war nicht gefragt");
    r = rSetzen();
    break;
```

Yet another way would be to throw an exception in the `default:`

```
default:
    throw new IllegalStateException("Dies war nicht gefragt");
    break;
```

This would prevent the code from reaching a `return r`.

> I just want to know [...] what I could do better

A better approach would be to use a loop instead of recursion for a problem that is not inherently recursive.

Comment: Thanks man. I( would be thinking the whole night long )Good to know how recursion really works :)

Comment: @Methredel This is not a good case for recursion, because currently it is a race between your end-users typing in a `"männlich"` or `"weiblich"`, and your system running out of stack space, whichever happens first. A `do`/`while` loop would let your program continue forever, but the depth of recursion is limited by the stack.

Comment: I just wanted to get a "Yes/No"-Question ( a Question with only two possible answers) in my code cause i have written a programm, which need in one case the variable r = 0.7; and in the other case r = 0.6 . Its used in a special formula for chemistry .

Answer (score 2):

You don't return when you recurse,

```
switch(gender){
    case "männlich": r = 0.7; break;
    case "weiblich": r = 0.6;break;
    default: System.err.println("Dies war nicht gefragt"); return rSetzen();
}
```

One possible improvement, might be to assume if the user isn't a "weiblich" then they must be a "männlich".

```
// This will test for equality, and consider "Weiblich" (note capitalization) 
// as equal.
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("weiblich")) {
  return 0.6;
}
return 0.7;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your call to rSetzen() in the default branch to a `return rSetzen()` instead.